# The set of all interior points. Set equality

Tags: general-topology

$(\overline{E})^o=E^o$. Is this equality true?

I proved that inclusion $E^o\subset (\overline{E})^0$ is true. But how to prove that inclusion $(\overline{E})^0\subset E^o$ is true or false?

$E^o$ the set of all interior points of $E$ and $\overline{E}$ is the closure of a set $E$.

Comment: Think about $E=(-1,0)\cup(0,1)$.

Comment: Thank you! It's really good example.

Answer (score 0):

It is false. Take for instance $E=\Bbb Q$ (in $\Bbb R$ with the usual topology).